# Problems with using Select2 and Bootstrap styling

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I'm trying to style my form using Bootstrap. I have a django-autocomplete-light control that uses Select2 and queries the database at the back-end.

I have tried to use the [Bootstrap Select 2 theme](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme)

however this breaks the remote data link, so all I get when I search is the Bootstrap placeholder for dropdowns.

Here is the relevant code:

*CSS / JS declarations*

```
    <link href="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2-bootstrap-theme/0.1.0-beta.6/select2-bootstrap.css" type = "text/css" media = "all" rel = "stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js"></script>



<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/collected/autocomplete_light/forward.js"></script>
```

*JQuery code in document.ready*

```
("#id_search").select2({theme:"bootstrap"});
```

*code in Django template*

```
<div class="p-2" body style="margin: 0;">
    {{ form.search.errors }}
    {{ form.search }}
</div>
```

*code in forms.py*

```
search = forms.ModelChoiceField(
    queryset=myobject.objects.all(),
    widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='my-autocomplete'), required = False
    )
```

*and finally, the rendered html*

```
<div class="p-2" body style="margin: 0;">

                            <select data-autocomplete-light-function="select2" data-autocomplete-light-url="/my-autocomplete/" id="id_search" name="search">
<option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
</select>

                        </div>
```

Please forgive my dreadful code - been out of the web dev game for 15 years and this project is my way of acclimatising myself back in!

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried implementing https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme ?

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing [select2 with bootstrap3](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme) 
Though, I think it's better if you use [select2](https://select2.org/getting-started/installation) and tweak on the CSS ([select2.min.js](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css)) and use the JS as it is.